# Node.js + Express - How to get Mustache partials working?

Tags: node.js, express, mustache

I'm trying to get Mustache working properly with Express, and as one can guess, I'm having troubles.

The following line initializes Mustache nice and clean. Variables render as expected.

```
app.register('html', require(__dirname+'/public/js/libs/mustache.js'));
```

However, the problems start to rise when partials are thrown in the mix. With Mustache, this here partial should invoke header view/partial.

```
{{> header}}
```

But alas, nothing happens. :/ Even when I offer the partial directly, Mustache fails to render it.

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('welcome', {
        partials: {
            header: '<h1>Header</h1>'           
        }
    });
});
```

So, it seems that the partials aren't working at all. I've found one hack that get's the partials somewhat working:

http://bitdrift.com/post/2376383378/using-mustache-templates-in-express

After that the partials render when offered directly at render call (see above), but it still fails on rendering the partials directly to views/layouts:

**Layout looks something like this:**

```
Behold, the header
{{> header}}
<p>Let's move to more important stuff...</p>
```

**Header view looks something like this:**

```
<h1>Header</h1>
```

Express can load the views by themselves just ok, but it doesn't know how to handle the Mustache partials...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managed to get this working with the latest version of hogan-express.

https://github.com/vol4ok/hogan-express

All that is needed is to install hogan-express and use it as template engine on express. No hacking or tuning required.

Comment: Any further comments on how you did or problems you encountered? to bootstrap someone's process just a little bit more ;) (Then I'll upvote)

Comment: All I did was install hogan-express and use it as template engine on express. :) No hacking or tuning required.

Answer (score 3):

Using express (at least version 3) and [mustache-express](https://github.com/bryanburgers/node-mustache-express#readme), You can load partials as usual using double mustaches that begin with a greater than sign.

First consider the following is appended within our `app.js` file:

```js
/** import the module */

import mustache from 'mustache-express';

/** view engine setup */

app.engine('mst', mustache());
app.set('view engine', 'mst');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'mvc/views'));

/** the route where we will display the partials */

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  let view = {
    title: 'Homepage',
    // ...
  };

  /** we are going to use a file called template.mst for rendering */
  res.render('template', view);
});
```

Any double mustaches that begin with a greater than sign (i.e. `{{> file}}`) will be considered a [partial](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js#partials). The file within the partial will be rendered at runtime. Consider this file to be a partial we want to insert:

**mvc/views/partial.mst**

```html
<h2>418 | I'm a teapot</h2>
```

And here is our template:

**mvc/views/template.mst**

```mst
<h1>template.mst file</h1>

<!-- output: <h2>418 | I'm a teapot</h2> -->
{{> partial}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what's exactly in your `./public/js/libs/mustache.js` ... I use the mustache module from npm + a variation of the templating object [you linked to](http://bitdrift.com/post/2376383378/using-mustache-templates-in-express%20%22%22).

In any case, the object you pass to `app.register` needs to call `mustache.to_html(template, locals, partials)` at some point.

You need to pass the partials object as the third argument to mustache's `to_html`.