# Partials rendering in Express.js and Mustache

Tags: express, mustache

I'm trying to load a Mustache partial in express.js, but obviously I'm having a bit of trouble. Is it possible to to take a EJS approach like this where a view partial file is included:

[Node.js - EJS - including a partial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404830/node-js-ejs-including-a-partial)

I have a template file called **index.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        {{>header}}
    </body>
</html>
```

and **header.mustache**

```
<div class="header">
    <div style="display: table-cell;padding-left: 10px;padding-top: 8px;vertical-align: middle;">
        <img src="images/logo.png">
    </div>
</div>
```

In express.js, my render function is something like this:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('signup.html', {
        partials: {
            header: partial('header.mustache')   //this line is wrong        
        }
    });
});
```

I'm a newbie at this, but would like to somehow render or read the entire contents of header.mustache to the header object. Is this possible?

Comment: The line is wrong? What's happening? Do you get an error message?

Comment: Yea, partial('header.mustache') returns an error

Comment: What is the error message then?

Comment: Oh, it basically says Object #<Object> has no method 'partial'. I'm not sure what the right method is to render the partial file.

Comment: What library are you using to render mustache? If it is [this one](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js), you have to call `Mustache.render`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node.js + Express - How to get Mustache partials working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10358053/node-js-express-how-to-get-mustache-partials-working)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the following link it might explain how you can setup mustache with express.js

[Using Mustache Templates in Express](http://bitdrift.com/post/2376383378/using-mustache-templates-in-exress)

Now for the being able to load partials from the external files modify the tmpl.compile to following

```
compile : function(source, options) {
    var views = options.views || './views';
    var extension = options.extension || '.html';

    if (typeof source == 'string') {
        return function(options) {
            options.locals = options.locals || {};
            options.partials = options.partials || {};

            if (options.body) // for express.js > v1.0
                locals.body = options.body;

            for(var p in options.partials) {
                var partialFileName = views + '/' + options.partials[p] + extension;

                if(path.existsSync(partialFileName)) {
                    options.partials[p] = fs.readFileSync(partialFileName, "utf-8");
                }
            }               
            return mustache.to_html(source, options.locals, options.partials);
        };
    } else {
        return source;
    }
}
```

You will also want to add following 2 require statements

```
var fs = require("fs"),
var path = require("path");
```

This change assumes that your partials are in `views` directory and end with extension `.html` (so for you example you might want to change the extension of your partial to .html or adjust the above code accordingly)

Now you can use following for partial rendering

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('signup.html', {
        partials: {
            header: 'header'   //this now works :)
        }
    });
});
```