# Using mustache.js partials with express

Tags: javascript, templates, node.js, express, mustache

So this may be a case of me completely misunderstanding functionality, but I am trying to use partials in node.js so that I have a reusable, reinsertable header and footer on my various templates similar to `{% extends 'something.html' %}` in django or `<? includes 'something.php ?>` in php. As I understand it this is what partials are for.

So in my app.js uses this configuration to render templates:

```
var mustache = require('mustache');
var template = {
    compile: function (source, options) {
        if (typeof source == 'string') {
            return function(options) {
                options.locals = options.locals || {};
                options.partials = options.partials || {};
                if (options.body) // for express.js > v1.0
                    locals.body = options.body;
                return mustache.to_html(
                    source, options.locals, options.partials);
            };
        } 
        else {
            return source;
        }
    },
    render: function (template, options) {
        template = this.compile(template, options);
        return template(options);
    }
};

// Configuration
app.configure(function(){
    app.register(".html", template);
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
    app.set('view options', {layout: false});
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(app.router);
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
});
```

and then I have this route:

```
var header = require("../views/header.html");

module.exports = function(app){
app.all('/test', function(req, res){
    var data = {
        locals: {value: "some value"},
        partials: {header: header}
    }
    res.render('test.html', data);
});
```

header.html is simply this:

```
hello world
```

and test.html is simply this:

```
{{>header}}
{{ value }}
```

I would expect that this would render:

```
hello world
some value
```

but I get an unexpected token error when I run `node app.js` pointing to `hello world` in my header.html as the problem.

what am I missing in configuring this so that it will work?

Comment: Save yourself a ton of headaches and use hulk-hogan (https://github.com/quangv/hulk-hogan). It supports layout files with `{{{body}}}`.

Comment: Yep using hulk-hogan solved my problem in about five seconds.  I would still be interested in knowing how to natively configure this though.

Comment: As the project page points out, there isn't really a good solution. Hence the project.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node.js + Express - How to get Mustache partials working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10358053/node-js-express-how-to-get-mustache-partials-working)

Answer (score 0):

For partials and how to make them work I would suggest taking a look at the [consolidate.js](https://github.com/visionmedia/consolidate.js) project. It's an efford to integrate multiple template engines with express 3.x

Comment: So it's basically putting back into expressjs what they took out? Seems to me taking out support for templates and partials from express was a mistake.

Comment: I like it when frameworks doesn't try to hold my hand for everything. Nobody wants to be stuck with the opinion of the author.

Comment: But surely taking things out is an opinionated action on the part of the author too.  Now we have to find other solutions to make our apps work with the new version.

Comment: Well for this particular removal it made sense to make it the responsibility of the template engine. What I understand was that it was a pita to support so many engine. For the next release res.render might be completely removed.

Answer (score 0):

This thread is very old but maybe someone beginner like me with mustache ends up like me here, with the same question.

In my case problem was I was omitting the ">" in the template..

- express: "^4.17.1"
- mustache-express: "^1.3.0"

in myRouter.ts

```
router.all('/', (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction)  => {
  res.render('index', {
    pageTitle: 'Welcome',
    partial: res.render('partial',{...})
  });
});
```

---

in template.mustache

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>{{pageTitle}}</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    {{>partial}}
   </body>
</html>
```

---

I wish this helps someone else