# mustache-express - create a sub-directory of partials for mustache

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mustache

I am using mustache ([mustache-express](https://github.com/bryanburgers/node-mustache-express/blob/master/README.md)) in my Node.js application for my view, and I decided to create a folder for my partials in my view directory like so:

```
view
  ├── partials
  │   ├── footer.mst
  │   └── header.mst
  ├── error.mst
  └── index.mst
```

Now whenever I request a partial, it should look for that partial at the partials directory:

```mst
<!-- should render the header partial -->
{{>header}}

<h1> {{title}} </h1>
<h3> {{message}} </h3>
<p>Welcome to {{title}}</p>

<!-- should render the footer partial -->
{{>footer}}
```

Is there a method to allow doing so?

Comment: Just FYI, here you're not using plural for "view", while in the answer you are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the README file for mustache-express, there is a section about [parameters](https://github.com/bryanburgers/node-mustache-express/blob/master/README.md#parameters)  that states:

> The mustacheExpress method can take two parameters: the directory of the partials and the extension of the partials.

So you can configure your view engine while passing the following parameters:

```js
/** import the module */
import mustache from 'mustache-express';

/** The path for your view directory */
const VIEWS_PATH = path.join(__dirname, '/views');

/**
 * Pass the path for your partial directory and
 * the extension of the partials within the mustache-express method
 */
app.engine('mst', mustache(VIEWS_PATH + '/partials', '.mst'));

/** View engine setup */
app.set('view engine', 'mst');
app.set('views', VIEWS_PATH);
```

Now you can use your partials like needed.

Comment: mustache is not defined. Please include more of the code -- did you mean mustacheExpress?  or are you doing another step first like `const mustache = mustacheExpress(VIEWS_PATH, '.mst');`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51729059/2848941 found it. you import mustacheExpress as just mustache. Good to know.

Comment: I have updated the answer to include the import. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: Also had to add var path = require('path'); before setting the VIEWS_PATH